# MySQL limit characters in multi-select query

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if there is a simple answer but I'm fairly new to MySQL and can't figure out how to explain this one:

I have a number of queries that select random words and concatenate them together. I'm trying to limit the query to only return results if they are under a specific character limit. So, for example, here's one query:

```
SELECT CONCAT((SELECT Word FROM Adjectives ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1),' ',
              (SELECT Word2 FROM Verbs ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1),' ',
              (SELECT Word FROM Nouns ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1))
```

It returns a result like "Adjective Verb Noun"

What I want to do is have the query check if the full concatenated result is 30 characters or less; if it is, return it, and if not, try it again until one with 30 or fewer characters is presented. Thanks!

UPDATE: This is for a fantasy football team name generator, that pulls "random" words from various tables and strings them together. So there are literally millions of possible combinations.... if the user specifies a character limit, I want SQL to re-try in the background until it finds and answer that fits, then present it. I don't want the user getting "please try again" kind of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to let SQL handle the decision making and finally spit out a string you want. I used an SQL procedure here.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `FETCH_STRING`(IN LEN INT)
    BEGIN

        declare TEMP varchar(100);
        declare isValid boolean;
        declare maxLength int;
        declare minLength int;

        set maxLength = LEN;
        set isValid = false;

        set minLength = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(n.word))+MIN(LENGTH(a.word))+MIN(LENGTH(v.word))+2 FROM NOUNS n, ADJECTIVES a, VERBS v);
        #That +2 in the end is compensating for two spaces in between
        if maxLength < minLength THEN
            set temp = "";
            set isValid = true;
        END IF; 

        WHILE isValid = false DO
            set temp = (SELECT CONCAT(
                    (SELECT Word FROM Adjectives ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1) ,' ',
                    (SELECT Word FROM Verbs ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1),' ',
                    (SELECT Word FROM Nouns ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1)));
            IF LENGTH(temp) <= maxLength THEN
                set isValid = true;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;            
    select temp;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This should do it. You can call it and always get a string matching your requirement. No need to process it again.

Is this what you were looking for ?

EDIT:
Added input field for length desired. And added condition to check if the given length is greater than the smallest possible concat and if so, return an empty string. This is to avoid infinite loop in the procedure.

Comment: I like this approach but I get the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Sorry. Unbalanced paranthesis in `set minLength` line. Fixed it. :)

Comment: Oops.. Unbalanced parantheses again. My Bad..!! Fixed. Should work now.

Comment: @nomistic: I thought the same initially. But, this is an effective and efficient (in terms of DB calls & execution time) solution. My consideration was to avoid multiple DB calls when the random selection does not meet the desired size. I'd say this is a trivial scenario to warrant multiple database calls. So, neither do we have to check if the returned string meets required length nor do we need to call the database again.

Comment: @SarathChandra I really want this to work.... but the same error keeps displaying. Everything seems right though, all your parentheses, etc.

Comment: @KielLamar: I think the issue is with the delimiter. I've fixed it. Hopefully, there shouldn't be anything else wrong.

Comment: @SarathChandra, thanks, that was it! I had to make a small mod to the beginning of the code:  
`DELIMITER $$  
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FETCH_STRING $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE ``FETCH_STRING`` (IN LEN INT)
    BEGIN`  
It just didn't like the "REPLACE OR CREATE" part for some reason.

Comment: Good to know that it worked finally. after so much of correction. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use strlen() to know how many characters contain the string:

```
$query_result = "MYSQL QUERY";

if(strlen($query_result) <= 30){
    echo $query_result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alias of your concatenated variables, such as words in your query, and then use php to check it

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT((SELECT Word FROM Adjectives ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1),' ',
              (SELECT Word2 FROM Verbs ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1),' ',
              (SELECT Word FROM Nouns ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1)) as words"

$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$words = $row['words'];
```

and then you could use something like `strlen()` to check the length

```
if (strlen($words)) > 30 {
 echo 'too many words';
```

and then spit out the form again.  you could embed it in here, this way you'd get the error, and then the form again, OR you could just have a display indicator like this:

```
     $display_form = 1;
}

else {
   echo $words;
  $display_form= 0;
}
```

===

**Edit - alternate answer to new clarification**

You can just do something like this:

```
SELECT words from
(SELECT CONCAT((SELECT Word FROM Adjectives ORDER BY Rand() limit 1 ),' ',
              (SELECT Word2 FROM Verbs ORDER BY Rand() limit 1),' ',
              (SELECT Word FROM Nouns ORDER BY Rand() limit)) as words) as temptable
where length(words) < 30
```

Comment: I think that "bla bla whatever you choose" is what I'm looking to define.... how can I make that re-run the query if the character limit is exceeded? I want this to be transparent to the end user, where the only see the final result.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question.    just kick out an error and then display the form again.  see edit

Comment: @KielLamar I was thinking about this and now I realize I'm more confused.   Why are you doing a database query if you are testing user input?  It wouldn't be in the database yet if it was over that amount?  Are you testing an input form or are people choosing sentences out of a pre-existing set of words?

Comment: Hi nomistic, I'll update the OP also.... this is for a fantasy football team name generator. So the user clicks "generate" and a new random name is generated (pulling one random word from Nouns, one random word from Adjectives, etc., among many other combinations). If they specify a character limit, I don't want them to get a "try again" message; I'd rather SQL just re-tries until it finds a suitable result and presents it.

Comment: fixed it again, I believe I made a mistake before (I haven't tested it)

Comment: I think it's getting closer, but this is no good:

Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Okay I see the problem.   This fix should work;  I tested it out with one of my own dbs.  You were right about that.   Let me know if this brings good results

Comment: This actually returns a blank string at times - when the random selection is longer than the given 30 characters. In that case, you have to catch it and call the query again.

Comment: SarathChandra is right -- this basically gives me the same result as my original query. I need something to tell SQL to run the query again if the result is over 30 characters.